# How to read a file in Scala with Play! 2.0?

Tags: scala, file, csv, playframework-2.0

I have a CSV file. Where should I place it and how do I read the file?

Comment: I wish to list all files in images directory, this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858808/how-to-list-out-all-the-files-in-the-public-images-directory-in-a-play-framework

Comment: onvert inputsteram to list of files

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this scala wrapper](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv) for [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). You can put your file on the classpath and then use `getClass.getResourceAsStream("file.csv")` to get an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `io.Source.fromFile("/public/myfile.csv")` also works for files outside of the classpath.

**Caveat:** For a *relative path* to your public folder you should start with `"public/..."` or `"./public/..."` instead of using the *absolute* path `"/public/..."`.

*(n.b. I didn't have the reputation to directly reply to comment by Luigi Plinge)*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the file under `/public`.

Then Read using

```
import scala.io.Source

val is = Application.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/public/myfile.csv")    
val src = Source.fromInputStream(is)
val iter = src.getLines
```

Comment: doesn't simply `val iter = io.Source.fromFile("/public/myfile.csv").getLines` work?

Comment: Using fromFile gave me `play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [FileNotFoundException: /public/myfile.csv (No such file or directory)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working here:

```
import java.io._

def index = Action {

    //Ok(views.html.index())

    Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File("../spark-backend/csv/UsersGroupedByRegistrationMonthYear.csv"))

}
```

There's some good documentation here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaStream