# How to list out all the files in the public/images directory in a Play Framework 2 Scala application?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to list out all the file names in the public/images directory for my Scala Play Framework 2 application so that the Play Application just lists those file names to the HTML page. How can this be done?

Is there a right way to access the public/images directory to read files or list the directory? I don't want to use absolute directory paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is method `getFile(relateivePath: String): File` on [`Play`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/play/api/Play$.html) object and also in the [`Application`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.Application) class which returns file relative to application root directory. In your case:

```
Play.getFile("public/images")
```

return [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object, which represent `public/images/`directory. You can call `list` or `listFiles` on it to get contents of the directory.

Comment: How will this give me a list of the files in the directory?

Comment: For Java version of Play 2.1.3 do Play.getFile("public/images", Play.current())

Comment: Starting 2.6, can use Environment.getFile() - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/Environment.html#getFile-java.lang.String-

Comment: For Java version of Play 2.4.11 do Play.application().getFile("public/images"), but it doesn't seem to work in production.